# How to make Validate Jquery Autocomplete combobox with asp requiredfieldvalidator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, autocomplete

I am using a required field validator to validate an autocomplete dropdownlist.

I am using jquery-ui. But the problem is it is not validating. The autocomplete code is copied from the jquery-ui website.

My code is:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=ddlSelectClient.ClientID%>").combobox();
});
```

**Html:**

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSelectClient" 
     AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" InitialValue="-1" 
     EnableViewState="false" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" 
     ControlToValidate="ddlParentProject" ErrorMessage="*" 
     data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" Title="Description Required" 
     CssClass="text-danger" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

How do I check If item initial value is -1

Comment: have a look at : [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310609/dropdownlist-validation-in-asp-net-using-required-field-validator)

Comment: @EnginÜstün i want to validate an autocomplete textbox

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633505/asp-customvalidator-doesnt-detect-text-changed-with-jquery-autocomplete